# center this css dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, menu

I am new here. Excuse me being a noob. I am a HS student seeking some help.

I cannot seem to paste my code so here's the link for jsfidlle

http://jsfiddle.net/zeusthunder10/WSD9f/6/

```
<body bgcolor="#D1D1D1">
<div align="center">
```

Comment: It is in Center...Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/WSD9f/7/

Comment: JSFiddle is an _excellent_ way to share this, it allows us all to play.  Can you be a bit more specific on what you're trying to center relative to what?

Comment: The dropdown menu is not centered. look, http://gyazo.com/24faa603abc01d45a2dfcdd6a2a85099

Comment: also is there a way to have jsfiddle put the javascript and css in the right place?

Comment: no there istn unfortunatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to center a block element like ul and without width is to use the trick `display: table` on the #navbar.

Also you need to add the missing `</ul>`

Jsfiddle fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/WSD9f/8/

Comment: Thank you so much! I literally spent the whole class today trying to figure out!

Answer (score 1):

You have the style

```
#navbar li { ... float: left; ... }
```

so all the `li`'s, you know, float to the left.

You probably want:

```
#navbar li { ... display: inline-block; ... }
```

Here's [your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WSD9f/9/) with that swap. IS that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't close the ul tag. You will want to put a /ul at the end of your list.

Try putting "display:inline-block;" in your #navbar class

```
#navbar {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 1em; 
   display:inline-block;}
```